# Why is Math.floor(Math.random()*9000) not secure in JavaScript?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness

I heard that one can predict the output from `Math.Random()` of JavaScript, but another day I had an idea to combine `Math.random()` with `Math.floor()` to make it harder to predict, but a week ago I saw [one user claimed that he can predict even if I used `Math.floor()` and that only takes 14 sample values to do that](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84906/predicting-math-random-numbers#comment458230_123554).

How is it possible mathematically?

---

The concrete construction in question is `Math.floor(Math.random()*9000)+1000`.

Various API specifications are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and [there](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#page=487). Per [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110241/71460) most browsers use Xorshift128+, possibly derived from this [C source code](http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/xorshift128plus.c).

In this [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/174881) the OP suggests that the question is about *"Chrome's V8 implementation"* and links to a [Chromium commit](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/ac66c97cfddc1e9fd89b494950ecf8a1a260bc80#diff-202872834c682708e9294600f73e4d15R111).

Comment: One is this [Why is Math.random() not designed to be cryptographically secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/181623/86735)

Comment: Do you understand why Math.random() is not secure and how you would go about determining the internal state? Can you adapt that process for the case where you only see the output of your transform?

Comment: @fgrieu I removed a bunch of comment discussion on this question, but edited in the gist of it which refers to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110241/71460) as the algorithmic source which claims Xorshift128+ for all / most implementations, so it's reasonable to assume Xorshift128+ here I suppose (I also edited this info into the question).

Comment: @fgrieu  My question is related to Chrome's V8 implementation.  They had changed the Xorshift128+ to something else, https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/ac66c97cfddc1e9fd89b494950ecf8a1a260bc80#diff-202872834c682708e9294600f73e4d15R111

Comment: "Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number" - Maybe, I see a possibility of occurrences where Math.floor() output original Math.rand() output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Math.random()` in [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#page=487)/JavaScript should return

> a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudorandomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy.

There's nothing to say that it is cryptographically secure, therefore the only prudent thing is to assume that it is not.

But that's not a concrete attack, much less against *"Chrome's V8 implementation"* as asked. One first needs to examine how `Math.random()` is used. Here we get that the application uses `Math.floor(Math.random()*9000)+1000`.

ECMA-262 specifies [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats)-2008 double-precision 64-bit binary format (52 explicit bits of mantissa + 1 implicit) with *"round to nearest, ties to even"* rounding (causing a relative error at most 2<sup>-54)</sup>). It follows that Math.random() outputs a value in [0 … 1 - 2<sup>-53</sup>], and `Math.floor(Math.random()*9000)+1000` outputs an integer about uniformly random in the set { 1000, 1001, …, 9999 }, thus with at most about ⌊log<sub>2</sub>(9000)⌋ ≈ 13.136 bits of entropy per output. The rest is unspecified by ECMA-262 and we need to dig into what implementations do.

---

My tentative analysis of the Chromium source [there](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:v8/src/numbers/math-random.cc) (lines 62/63 and what it links to), and that of [Firefox 47.0](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/74.0/source/) and [Safari's Webkit](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WTF/wtf/WeakRandom.h#L64) (which is the clearest), concludes that the next value of `Math.random()` for these is as if generated by:

```
uint64_t state0, state1;    // the 128-bit state

// update state and produce a double
double MathRandom(void) {
  uint64_t s0 = state1;  // notice the swap
  uint64_t s1 = state0;
  s1 = s1 ^ (s1 << 23);
  s1 = s1 ^ (s1 >> 17) ^ (s0 >> 26) ^ s0;
  state0 = s0;
  state1 = s1;
  if (Firefox || Webkit) // Firefox v47.0, Webkit 2019-07 thru 2020-02
    return (double)( (s0+s1) & (((uint64_t)1<<53)-1) ) / ((uint64_t)1<<53);
  else                   // ChromX V8, 2019-01 thru 2020-02
    return (double)(  s0     >> 12                   ) / ((uint64_t)1<<52);
}
```

That's significantly different from the [Xorshift128+ source](http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/xorshift128plus.c) linked in the question: the shift constants are different, and for ChromX V8 the 64-bit addition is gone.

---

In all versions, because 9000 ≥ 2<sup>13</sup>, each output of `Math.floor(Math.random()*9000)+1000` lets us be certain of up to 13 bits (of bits 63…51 of `s0` for ChromX V8, of bits 52…10 of `s0+s1` for Firefox/Webkit). Being certain of the top j bits of that segment has probability more than 1-2<sup>j-13</sup>.

The ChromX V8 version is entirely linear: each of the 128 bits of the state is a combination by XOR of the bits of the previous state, thus (by induction) of any earlier state¹. 52 bits of the state make it *directly* to the output of `Math.random`, thus the above j ≲ 13 bits that we get at each step directly are state bits. With a little more than 10 (computed as ⌈128/13⌉ ) consecutive outputs² from the same thread, the state of the generator can be found by Gaussian elimination and the rest (before/after) predicted. That's a mere technicality. I'll try to link to a code snippet.

The Firefox/Webkit version is harder, because it has the addition modulo 2<sup>64</sup> of the original Xorshift128+. Still, while the output is non-linear, the state evolves linearly, and an efficient attack is feasible with a little more consecutive outputs², by expressing what's known in the framework of a satisfiability problem and submitting to a state of the art SAT solver. That's essentially what was done in [this attack](https://blog.securityevaluators.com/hacking-the-javascript-lottery-80cc437e3b7f#.mwvrmr6aq), yet with much more bits of state leaking at each step, making it easier.

In [these](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/174903) [three](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/175987) [comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/175997), Poncho describes an explicit attack strategy for the Firefox/Webkit version. That goes:

- We assume that the values obtained from `Math.floor(Math.random()*9000)+1000` are enough to consistently give us the 9 bits 52…44 of the the fraction of bits 52…40 of `s0+s1` that we can observe; if not, we guess a few bits, multiplying our later work by a small factor (no longer considered below).
- We guess the 9 corresponding bits 52…40 of the initial `state1`, and of the carry bit that occurs from bit 39 to 40 in the addition `s0+s1` for the first output that we can observe. In `s0+s1`, the operand `s0` is that of our guess, thus we can compute the corresponding new `s1`.
- Each of the 9 bits of that new `s1` is a known linear combination of bits of the initial state, and that gives us 9 equations for a Gaussian elimination aiming at finding the full initial state.
- Moving to the next output, we need to guess only the carry bit that occurs from bit 39 to 40 in the addition `s0+s1` in order to maintain running knowledge of the corresponding new `s1`, and obtain 9 additional equations for Gaussian elimination.
- With about ⌈(128-9)/9⌉ = 14 outputs of the RNG, we have enough equations to solve the system, allowing to validate our guesses.
- We have to solve in the order of 2<sup>9+14</sup> systems, which is quite manageable.

---

Notes:

¹ That's a design feature of Xorshift128+, making it easy to compute an arbitrary portion of the output sequence.

² We could also exploit outputs at known positions in the output, e.g. one out of N values in the set { 1000, 1001, …, 9999 } obtained by a particular player in a game involving a known number N of players.

Comment: Actually, in the comments to my answer, I outlined an attack (brief to fit within the allowed space of a comment) that allowed an attacker to get enough internal bits of the Firefox version to allow Gaussian elimination to recover the state...

Comment: @poncho: Won't challenge you on being first to post a solution! I linked to your nice comment.

Comment: @fgrieu This is a excellent write up.

Comment: @fgrieu Would love to see the stuff unspecified by ECMA-262

Comment: @fgrieu I've used script to predict the seed but one has to be fast enough to generate enough samples using a Loop and If one console.log Math.random() one by one to get samples then it will won't work. So generally I believe it seems impossible to predict seed when the code used in Server Side as network latency affects the speed. Maybe there are other ways that I can't think of.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628408/math-random-follows-which-algorithms), math.random uses a Linear Congruential Generator (although it is not clear to me if that's on one specific browser, or on all JavaScript implementations).

In any case, a Linear Congruential Generator is known not to be secure, in the sense that, given partial output (which the Math.floor( 9000 * Math.random() ) operation allows), someone is able to reconstruct the initial seed, and from that, reconstruct the entire sequence.

In particular, if the browser uses the popular XORSHIFT128+ RNG, and you are able to deduce 128 lsbits from the underlying 32 bit outputs, you can reconstruct the initial state (by solving some binary linear equations).

Comment: Question is how one can construct seed if one used Math.Floor?

Comment: Math.floor() create different decimals to the original Math.rand() output

Comment: The question is about Math.float combined with Math.random. It's my understanding that you need original outputs of Math.random to predict seed. With Math.float the original output get changed.

Comment: Typo mistake. It's Math.floor()

Comment: @sqlbie: actually, from what I read (I don't use JavaScript myself), it appears that it's not unusual for an implementation to use a fixed seed (in which case it's easy).  In any case, the 32 bit output -> float mapping that Math.random does would leak some information about the 32 bit XORSHIFT128 outputs

Comment: @sqlbie: I looked over the XORSHIFT128 algorithm, it would appear that, with about 8 successive $floor(9000*(XORSHIFT128 / 2** 32))$ outputs, you should be able to reconstruct the seed (even if it were randomly chosen)

Comment: @sqlbie: that's assuming the Firefox version; analysis of the ChromeX version is trivial (as it is completely bitwise linear internally...)

Comment: @poncho Interesting. Why it has to be 8? I lack the mathematical knowledge to understand why it need 8 to reconstruct seed from Math.floor outputs.

Comment: @sqlbie: minor correction - with the Firefox XORSHIFT128 algorithm, it would actually take circa 12 outputs, not 8 as I stated earlier...

Comment: @sqlbie: as for how you attack it, first of all, XORSHIFT128 is internally bitwise linear, and so if we get 128 (or a few more) linear equations, we can derive the seed.  The output gives the high 13 bits or so (with some ambiguity at times) of the value s0+s1.  So, we guess the top 10 bits of the initial s0; that gives us the top 10 bits of initial s1.  then, the next 9 bits high output is a function of the top 9 bits of s0, top 9 bits of s1, and the bottom 9 bits of s1 - that allows us to deduce the bottom 9 bits of s1 (and so, 9 more linear equations).  Each output gives us 9 more bits.

Comment: I have doubts for the Firefox case. If the final `double` construction in my code [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/78478/555) is right (and at least it matches earlier independent analysis), what we get from `Math.floor(Math.random()*9000)+1000` gives bits 52..40 (with uncertainty in the low bits) of $s0+s1$. And then I fail to see a local approach where a guess of state bits yields more state bits than was guessed. I'm still entirely confident that the problem can be attacked with ample consecutive output, because the state evolves linearly.

Comment: @fgrieu: the guessing applies only to the top bits of the initial $s0, s1$ values; after that, each iteration gives you 9 bottom bits of $s1$ (with the only guessing may be due to a carry bit) - this takes advantage of the only leftward shift within xorshift128 `s1 = s1 ^ (s1 << 23);` - since we know (assume) the value of `s1` before the operation, and can deduce the value afterwards, that allows us to deduce the value `(s1 << 23)`; that is, the bottom 9 bits

Comment: Sorry, I still do not get it. One problem is that the output of Firefox does _not_ ≈give the high 13 bits of s0+s1; it ≈gives bits 52..40 of s0+s1. Yes, there's a single left shift (by 23, which implies that the fraction 52..41 that we most directly observe does not propagate left on the next round), but I fail to see how that allows learning ≈9 more state bits from each observation after some amount of initial guess.

Comment: @fgrieu: it appears I got some details wrong; however the base idea appears to be valid.  At step x, we have s0, s1, and we output some outputs of s0+s1, and we'll assume we know those bits of s0, s1.  Then, at step x+1, the algorithm sets s0' = s1, and s1' to be some linear function of s0, s1, and outputs s0'+s1'.  Now, we know those bits of s0', and since we see some bits of s0'+s1', we can deduce those bits of s1' (assuming a carry in, which we don't know); if we see 9 bits of s0'+s1', that gives us 9 bits of s1' (at the cost of assuming 1 carry bit).

Comment: I don't think that works as it. The top 9 bits of the fraction of s0+s1 that we can observe are bits 52..44 of that sum. These depend on: a carry bit; on bits 52..44 of earlier s1 (becoming the new s0); and from earlier s0 on bits 52..44, 29..21 (thru <<23), 40..38 (thru <<23 >>17), and 63..61 (thru >>17). Thus if we guess the bits of 52..44 of s0 and s1, at each step we learm about 9 bits from the RNG output, but 16 (initialy) unknown bits creep in. But your principle may work if we maintain the top 6 bits of the observable fraction of s0+s1 (retroaction by <<23 >>17 and >>17 vanishes).

Comment: @fgrieu: "and from earlier s0 on bits 52..44, 29..21 (thru <<23), 40..38 (thru <<23 >>17), and 63..61 (thru >>17)."; that is, it's a linear function of those bits (and hence we can form a linear equation relating the bit we see and the bits they're a linear function of.  The only bit that acts nonlinearly is the carry bit; we need to assume that.

Comment: Got it now, thanks for your patience. Yes, the RNG output gives us all except about 1 bit of the info we need to maintain current an initial guess of state1, and while that does not directly reveals state bits, that gives us linear equations that build up to the whole state after 14 RN values or so, and manageably little guesses.